# Не копируется файл с помощью функции CopyFile

Tags: c++

Хочу чтобы мой .exe файл копировал сам себя в определенное место. Я использую функцию CopyFile, но она почему-то не работает. Я думал что проблема в том что .exe файл не может копировать себя-же. Но я пробовал с обычными .txt файлами и ничего не получается. Все пути полученные в ходе программы я проверял, они действительные.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define DEBUG
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<filesystem>
#include<fstream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<MMSystem.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<direct.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char ThatExe[MAX_PATH] = "";
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    strcat(ThatExe, "C:\\1\\hi.exe");

    int a = CopyFile((LPWSTR)buffer, (LPWSTR)ThatExe, true);

    if (a) std::cout << "file copy"     << std::endl;
    else   std::cout << "file not copy" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну вызовите вы GetLastError, да посмотрите что пошло не так.

Comment: А как его вызывать ?

Comment: вот что не могу понять. Почему имя исходного файла wchar_t. А имя результирующего char ? Привести к одному типу и посмотреть. GetLastError() если FALSE код возврата  копирования выдаст НОМЕР ошибки

Comment: А как привести к одному типу если оно начинает ругаться?

Comment: @maint прав, при приведении char* к wchar* в строке `CopyFile((LPWSTR)buffer, (LPWSTR)ThatExe, true);` получается ахинея вместо имени файла. Ищите в папке с проектом файл в имени которого какие-нибудь иероглифы/кракозябры - это и есть ваш скопированный файл.

Comment: на что тут ругаться? В каком месте? . Не на strcat случайно дурацкий? А что функции типа wcscpy не знакомы, для работы с wchar_t?

Comment: А как быть с тем что я пробовал вручную предавать пути к файлам и все равно не получилось

Comment: куда в ручную, опять в char?

Comment: А понял. Как приконкотинировать char к wchar_t?

Comment: Мне нужно просто еще дополнительный путь указать wcscpy(ThatExe, "C:\\1\\hi.exe"); - ругается на строку

Comment: вы вообще различаете char и wchar_t. Первая однобайтовая кодировка, вторая многобайтовая кодировка символов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126582/discussion-between---and-maint).

Answer (score 2):

```
wchar_t ThatExe[MAX_PATH];

wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

wcscpy(ThatExe, L"C:\\\\1\\\\hi.exe");

int a = CopyFile((LPWSTR)buffer, (LPWSTR)ThatExe, true);

if (a) std::cout << "file copy"     << std::endl;

else   {
 std::cout << "file not copy" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ругается на первую строчку(w_char не определен) и на 4 тоже не определен

Comment: описка, поправлю сейчас

Comment: Теперь ругается только на wcspy((

Comment: хедер поставили ?

Comment: #include <wchar.h>

Comment: По прежнему происходит тоже самое

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126583/discussion-between---and-maint).

Comment: посмотрите в хелпе своего компилятора, я не знаю какой у вас, скопировать строку в строку. Я все, а то поехали, что бы сделал за вас